How to extract, save and/or access pyvis.network manipulation changes in Shiny?
I'm creating a shiny app on python including network from pyvis. I enabled manipulation, so I can add nodes and deleted. An user would like to interact with and save the final network created by adding and deleting nodes and edges from the manipulation bar:
manipulaion bar
I saw the solution for R on this page: How to extract and save visNetwork manipulation changes in Shiny?, but I can't find any solution on R.
I need to know the manipulation changes whenever a change is made.

I guess you should use reactive.value to save inputs. Instead of R assigments, like initialising:
links_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
elements_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
links_data(df)  # or df <- links_data()

where df is the "from" "to" dataframe, you should use in Python Shiny:
links_data = reactive.value(NULL)
links_data.set()
links_data.get()

for setting and getting data within the @reactive.effect @reactive.event(input.table) segment.
There is a short example in the shiny for python docs how to use it in the reactive framework for single values:
https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/core/reactive.value.html#:~:text=Reactive%20values%20are%20the%20source,are%20read%2Donly%20reactive%20values
Actually I wonder whether you have managed to get PyVis with Shiny - I gave up after several days... The visualization never worked as expected...
